# Mongodb Compass: Connection timed out

Tags: mongodb, server, ubuntu-16.04, forge

I installed `Mongodb` on my remote server using [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/?_ga=2.163427893.869720277.1670404556-1140193615.1668599249) documentation. I have `Ubuntu 16.04` on my remote server. `Mongodb` got installed successfully. I added the user like this:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: 'myuser',
    pwd: 'password',
    roles: [ { role: 'readWrite', db: 'mydb' } ]
  }
);
```

I also made changes in the `mongod.conf` like this:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,<server_ip>

security:
  authorization: 'enabled'
```

Now when I try to connect to `mongodb` using conneciton string like this:

```
mongodb://myuser:password@server_ip:27017/mydb
```

It gives me the following error:

> connection timed out

What am I doing wrong here? I am using `Laravel Forge` to manage sever.

Comment: Instead of `bindIp: 127.0.0.1,<server_ip>` I suggest `bindIpAll: true`. Using `bindIp: <ip_address>` makes only sense when your computer has multiple network interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out the port was not open and that was the only issue. Opened the port and now its working fine.